# Cartesian product of two tables

Tags: python

I have the following tables in the format

```
{str:list of str}  
table1 = {key1:['1','2','3'], key2: ['3','4','5']}  
table2 = {key3:['6','7','8','9'], key4:['9','10','11','12']}
```

Now I need to get the cartesian product of the two without using itertools or sql commands.

I basically need the new table to be:

```
new_table = {key1:['1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','3','3','3','3'], 
             key2: ['3','3','3','3','4','4','4','4','5','5','5','5'],
             key3: ['6','7','8','9','6','7','8','9'],
             key4: ['9','10','11','12','9','10','11','12']}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: How did `key5` come in?

Comment: I have no idea what you want, except that it's definitely *not* a Cartesian product.

Comment: sorry that was suppose to be key4. it was a typo and also those key names should have quotes, my bad.

Comment: @TimPeters: I think there's a product lurking.  This looks like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962840/cartesian-product-for-two-dictionaries-python) with an added no-itertools restriction.  (Of course this assumes that the desired output is actually incorrect, but it wouldn't be the first time..)

Comment: So you want each element of the first list repeated 4 times, ditto for the 2nd, but you want two copies of the 3rd and 4th lists pasted together?  LOL - sorry, but this makes no sense ;-)

Comment: @DSM, could be! But it's not interesting enough to stick around to find out ;-)

Comment: This looks like a task best handled with the [`DWIM` instruction](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/D/DWIM.html). Unfortunately, I am not aware of a currently maintained Python implementation of it.

Comment: @user3050527, not really - it's extraordinarily helpful, but you have to make *some* effort to ask a sensible question. You're getting ragged on only because your question makes mud look clear ;-)

Answer (score 5):

```
table1 = {"key1":['1','2','3'], "key2": ['3','4','5']}  
table2 = {"key3":['6','7','8','9'], "key4":['9','10','11','12']}
n1, n2 = 4, 2
r1 = {k:[i for i in v for j in range(n1)] for k, v in table1.items()}
r2 = {k:v * n2 for k, v in table2.items()}
r1.update(r2)
print r1
```

**Output**

```
{'key3': ['6', '7', '8', '9', '6', '7', '8', '9'], 'key2': ['3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5'], 'key1': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3'], 'key4': ['9', '10', '11', '12', '9', '10', '11', '12']}
```

Comment: If you successfully figured out what he wanted you have 10 eyes...

Answer (score 3):

I have a much simpler solution:

```
new_table = {'key1': ['1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','3','3','3','3'], 
             'key2': ['3','3','3','3','4','4','4','4','5','5','5','5'],
             'key3': ['6','7','8','9','6','7','8','9'],
             'key4': ['9','10','11','12','9','10','11','12']}
```

That gives you exactly what you want, with no need for `itertools` or even a tiny attempt at explaining *why* that's the result you want ;-)

Comment: thanks! i used this and it actually worked lol idk why i spent so much time on this when it was so simple

Comment: @Tim Peters I thought you were joking when I saw this answer.I can't stop laughing. ha ha ha ha ha ha ha ha

Comment: Joking? I never joke ;-) But methinks @user3050527 was being sarcastic with his response. Easier than explaining what they wanted ;-)